# Insert XML data into the existing posts

Tags: php, xml, database, wordpress, xml-parsing

I have nba videos news website and I want to insert xml data into the existing posts.

For ex I have this post Pacers vs Timberwolves Match report and I want to import data from this xml: http://developer.sportradar.us/files/nba_v3_game_boxscore_example.xml

I know how to echo and get data from xml feeds but my problem is how to assign automatically these xml feeds based on each posts (match reports) .

1. I need to collect data first and store it at my local DB?
2. Retrieve a specific field from taxonomy term OR custom field term and use it on xml url's ex http(s)://api.sportradar.us/nba/[season]/games/[game_id]/summary.xml?api_key=[api_key] ?

Also as alternative I can use JSON feeds.